# Get Links From Web Page

Tags: c#, javascript, python, ruby, imacros

I need to get all the item links(URLs) from this webpage into a text file delimited by breaks (in other words a list like so: "Item #1"  "Item #2"  etc.

http://dota-trade.com/equipment?order=name is the webpage and if you scroll down it goes on and on to about ~500-1000 items.

What programming language would I have to use or how would I be able to do this. I also have experience using imacros already.

Comment: It should be possible with C#, Python and maybe Ruby. Javascript will be tricky, though. If you are asking, how many programming languages could do this in general, there would be too many to list them all here.

Comment: What do you think would be the easiest language to do this in? The only reason I added javascript is because i'm familiar with using imacros, and I can get javascript in there using the EVAL command. Maybe someone would know how to do it through imacros.

Comment: From the three mentioned, I would recommend Python. Or let's put it this way: What programming languages did you learn already?

Comment: I did a beginners tutorial on Python, but it was pretty short. That's about it. What do you think about using lxml in python to do this?

Comment: I don't know enough about HTML processing with Python and I am also not sure if you need extra libraries when it should be possible without any additional ones. Approach it logical: Read about how you can access and edit .txt files with Python. Inform yourself about accessing web content with Python. Look for tutorials on processing the HTML and storing it in a .txt file.

Comment: I'm new to this site, so if you could tell me how this is off topic it would help me word my future questions appropriately. To ask this question, I was going off the help center "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" point. This is a specific problem that warrants a specific solution. The responses are great, and I am currently trying them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download HtmlAgilityPack

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            var sourceCode = wc.DownloadString("http://dota-trade.com/equipment?order=name");
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(sourceCode);
            var node = doc.DocumentNode;
            var nodes = node.SelectNodes("//a");
            List<string> links = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in nodes)
            {
                var link = item.Attributes["href"].Value;
                links.Add(link.Contains("http") ? link : "http://dota-trade.com" +link);
            }
            int index = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                sourceCode = wc.DownloadString("http://dota-trade.com/equipment?order=name&offset=" + index.ToString());
                doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(sourceCode);
                node = doc.DocumentNode;
                nodes = node.SelectNodes("//a");
                var cont = node.SelectSingleNode("//tr[@itemtype='http://schema.org/Thing']");
                if (cont == null) break; 
                foreach (var item in nodes)
                {
                    var link = item.Attributes["href"].Value;
                    links.Add(link.Contains("http") ? link : "http://dota-trade.com" + link);
                }
                index++;
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\WriteLines.txt", links);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code worked. Just for notes I used Microsoft visual Studio Ultimate 2012 RTM. I installed it (took almost 2 hours). I launched Visual Studio 2012. I clicked "File" then "New Project", then under "Installed -> Templates -> Visual C# -> Windows -> Console Application" then press "ok". A new page should appear named Program.cs. Paste what Kubik made into the window overwriting what's already there.

Comment: Download HtmlAgilityPack. I got mine from http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ Now click "Project" then click "Add Reference". Once the Reference Manager pops up click "Browse" and then click "Browse" at the bottom right of the popup. Navigate to the HtmlAgilityPack.dll in the Net45 folder of the HtmlAgilityPack that you downloaded. Now Press "ok" and press F5. Should work like a charm.

Comment: Now that the notes are done. If you look on the http://dota-trade.com/equipment?order=name page and you scroll down,  you'll see that the page keeps scrolling. So your code picks up all of the links that the page can see, but not the ones you can see if you have scrolled down. How can the code be made so that it pulls the sourceCode of the entire page including the scrolled down part?

Comment: Code edited, even the scrolled down part is downloaded now.

Comment: You are an absolute godsend. Thank you so much. You should answer the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668141/c-sharp-code-only-getting-pagesource-for-visible-page-not-for-scrolled-down-pag so that people searching would be able to find it. I'll also tag that question as answered so that you get your points!

Comment: I have since tried to get your code to do the same thing from multiple webpages to no avail. I made a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686390/use-this-code-for-multiple-webpages I'm sure it's something very small, but I just can't figure it out. I would really appreciate it if you could help me!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using any language with Regular Expression support.  I use ruby a lot so I would do something like this:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("http://dota-trade.com/equipment?order=name")

req = Net::HTTP::Get(uri.path)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
response = http.request(request)

links = response.body.match(/<a.+?href="(.+?)"/)
```

This is off the top of my head but links[0] should be a match object, every element there after is a match.

```
puts links[1..-1].join("\n")
```

The last line should dump what you want but likely won't include the host.  If you want the host included do something like this:

```
puts links[1..-1].map{|l| "http://dota-trade.com" + l }.join("\n")
```

Please keep in mind this is untested.