# C# Code only getting pagesource for visible page, not for scrolled down page

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2012

If you go to http://dota-trade.com/equipment?order=name and scroll down, you can see that if you scroll down to the bottom of the page, it loads more items. The following code grabs all of the links from the webpage and saves it into a text file. Right now it is only grabbing all of the visible links. How is it possible to grab all of the links including the ones that appear as you scroll down?

If you know a better way to describe what I'm asking please edit my post, you have my full permission to edit anything to your desired preference. Thank you.

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            var sourceCode = wc.DownloadString("http://dota-trade.com/equipment?order=name");
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(sourceCode);
            var node = doc.DocumentNode;
            var nodes = node.SelectNodes("//a");
            List<string> links = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in nodes)
            {
                var link = item.Attributes["href"].Value;
                links.Add(link.Contains("http") ? link : "http://dota-trade.com" +link);
                Console.WriteLine(link.Contains("http") ? link : "http://dota-trade.com" + link);
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\WriteLines.txt", links);
        }
    }
}
```

Additional Information: Here's everything I did from the start to finish:

I used Microsoft visual Studio Ultimate 2012 RTM. I installed it (took almost 2 hours). I launched Visual Studio 2012. I clicked "File" then "New Project", then under "Installed -> Templates -> Visual C# -> Windows -> Console Application" then press "ok". A new page should appear named Program.cs. Paste the code into the window overwriting what's already there. Download HtmlAgilityPack. I got mine from htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com Now click "Project" then click "Add Reference". Once the Reference Manager pops up click "Browse" and then click "Browse" at the bottom right of the popup. Navigate to the HtmlAgilityPack.dll in the Net45 folder of the HtmlAgilityPack that you downloaded. Now Press "ok" and press F5. Should work like a charm. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            var sourceCode = wc.DownloadString("http://dota-trade.com/equipment?order=name");
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(sourceCode);
            var node = doc.DocumentNode;
            var nodes = node.SelectNodes("//a");
            List<string> links = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in nodes)
            {
                var link = item.Attributes["href"].Value;
                links.Add(link.Contains("http") ? link : "http://dota-trade.com" +link);
            }
            int index = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                sourceCode = wc.DownloadString("http://dota-trade.com/equipment?order=name&offset=" + index.ToString());
                doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(sourceCode);
                node = doc.DocumentNode;
                nodes = node.SelectNodes("//a");
                var cont = node.SelectSingleNode("//tr[@itemtype='http://schema.org/Thing']");
                if (cont == null) break; 
                foreach (var item in nodes)
                {
                    var link = item.Attributes["href"].Value;
                    links.Add(link.Contains("http") ? link : "http://dota-trade.com" + link);
                }
                index++;
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\WriteLines.txt", links);
        }
    }
}
```